# FFT returns SINC instead of distinct peaks

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft

I tried two different implementations of FFT in C# and both are giving me some strange results. To create a minimal test I really came down to single normalized (all params = 1) cosine wave which I supply to the FFT but instead of getting single peak at 1Hz, I am getting some function resembling cardinal sine (SINC). Now that's a little weird as SINC should be result of FFT for some flat box function.  I'm out of ideas what could cause this behavior and just to be sure I ran a demo that shows the expected results [here](http://madebyevan.com/dft/).

I'm currently using this [implementation of FFT](http://www.lomont.org/Software/Misc/FFT/LomontFFT.html), but same results were with ExoCortex 1.2.
Here's the screenshot of result of FFT in frequency domain on left and the signal in time domain on right.
[image: fft]

Comment: I'm guessing that it's because the theoretical Fourier inverse of a cosine function is a single impulse when you take the cosine from its whole infinite domain. What you have here is a part of a cosine function, so the inverse is not exactly a single delta. You might get more accurate answers here, on [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Signal Processing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice there's dedicated site for SP.. SE network is getting quite large.

Comment: I think what you're seeing here is just spectral leakage (google for it).

Comment: Real input signals are rarely perfect, you just can't make an infinite sine wave.  Your cosine is problematic, it has spikes from 0 to MAX at the start and close to MAX back to 0 at the end.  These fast transitions generate a lot of 3rd order harmonics, like a square wave does, you can see them back well in the frequency spectrum.  It will look better when you start and end at 0.  A [*window function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) is required to suppress the artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Nils Pipenbrinck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15955/nils-pipenbrinck) noted, this was the case of very bad spectral leakage. Using window function ([Blackman–Nuttall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function)) as suggested by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) and transforming my time domain signal to sine wave rather than cosine resulted in huge improvement, where I basically get narrow bell with maximum at right frequency. This is therefore the optimal solution and both commenters deserve credit.

Answer (score 1):

Any finite length sinusoid is essentially windowed by a box or rectangle.  You will only see a single peak if the length of the FFT is an exact integer multiple of the period of a sinusoid, and the sinusoid extends unmodulated the full length of that FFT.

Your sinusoid is either too short, and/or not integer periodic in the FFT length.